# With RubyGems, is it possible to copy/delete files when installing/uninstalling gems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a Ruby application that employs a plugin architecture, wherein it looks in the current user's home directory to see if plugins exist in a particular location. I'd like to be able to package plugins as RubyGems, and when a gem is installed have files contained in the gem copied to the user's plugin directory. In addition, I'd also want the files to be deleted from the user's plugin directory when the gem is uninstalled.

Is this possible with RubyGems? I notice that the Gem module has some install/uninstall hooks, but from what I can tell by reading and testing some code these hooks apply to all Gems processed after the hooks are installed rather than just being used for a particular gem.

I've also done some things upon install of a gem via a Rakefile included with the gem, but I don't know if I could do the same thing with a Rakefile when gems are uninstalled.

Any advice?!

Comment: while you can do stuff like this (and i did that for some jruby stuff), it's not considered a good practice to do something like this from your gem install or uninstall. i'm not aware of anything you can do during uninstallation of a gem. i would recommend writing a rake task for the setup and implode methods if really necessary.